# Play framework empty session

Tags: java, session, playframework

Could somebody please explain how session works in Play Framework? Yes-yes, I've already read the official documentation and couldn't find what the problem was.

Within a controller I have two action methods. In the first action I put a variable into the session and expect it there during the second request (which is AJAX) to another action. But it's not there :(

I have it something like this:

```
public class MyController extends Controller {
    private static final String SESSION_VAR_NAME = "SESSION_VAR_NAME";

    public CompletionStage<Result> action1() {
        // Store session variable
        session(SESSION_VAR_NAME, "SomeVal");
    }

    public Result action2() {
        // Expect "SomeVal" but get null instead
        String sessionVal = session(SESSION_VAR_NAME);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was quite simple. It was just a bug in Play 2.6.0. Upgrading to 2.6.2 solved the issue.